# Active is not working on my jquery filter

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to make active class on each category so each time I click on different category it shifts to other one but I am failing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list-inline-item').click(function() {
    const value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    if (value == 'all') {
      $('.clients').show('1000');
    } else {

      $('.clients').not('.' + value).hide('1000');
      $('.clients').filter('.' + value).show('1000');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.list-inline-item {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 15px;
}

.active {
  color: #b42727;
  background-color: white;
}

.list-inline-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid clientbox text-center py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul>
        <li class="list-inline-item active" data-filter="all">ALL</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" data-filter="B">B</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" data-filter="C">C</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" data-filter="D">D</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" data-filter="M">M</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" data-filter="U">U</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" data-filter="C">C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>

    <div class="clients D col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img class=" img-fluid " src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/27/52/orange-stock-iamge-vector-37112752.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients D col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img class=" img-fluid " src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/27/52/orange-stock-iamge-vector-37112752.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients D col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img class=" img-fluid " src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/27/52/orange-stock-iamge-vector-37112752.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients D col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img class=" img-fluid " src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/27/52/orange-stock-iamge-vector-37112752.jpg" alt=""></div>


    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="clients B col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3"><img class="img-fluid " src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

The code is working fine all is good but the active class is not specific for each category I guess I have to edit the j query code but I am not sure about it

Comment: Please don't [SHOUT](https://www.lifewire.com/why-not-to-write-in-all-caps-1173242)

Comment: TBH your question is unclear.   What do you consider a "category"?   Could you try using different images so it's clearer what's going on?  "*so each time I click on different category it shifts to other one*" so it selects a random category when you click on one? "active class" - you don't seem to be setting the active class and it's not clear what you would want to set it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the jquery part to

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.list-inline-item').click(function(){
        const value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        if(value == 'all'){
            $('.clients').show('1000');
        }
        else{ 

            $('.clients').not('.'+value).hide('1000');
            $('.clients').filter('.'+value).show('1000');
        }

        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    })
})
```